# How do I stop my python script becoming unresponsive?

Tags: python, macos

im really new to programming and I was trying to use my knowledge to make an autoclicking app that repeatedly clicks the left mouse button whilst f6 is pressed. Im writing and running the code on a mac. My issue is that it all works well, but when I release f6, it does stop clicking as intended but the app window then becomes unresponsive and needs to be force quit. Is there any way around this as it limits functionality severely?

```
import tkinter as tk
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import pyautogui


def clicker():
    def on_press(key):
        if key == Key.f6:
            pyautogui.click(button='left')

    def on_release(key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            # Stop listener
            return False

    with Listener(
            on_press=on_press,
            on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()


window = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(
    master=window,
    text='click me',
    command=clicker,
    height=10,
    width=20
)

button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Updated Code:

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import pyautogui


def helper():
    h = threading.Thread(target = clicker, daemon=True)
    h.start()


def clicker():
    def on_press(key):
        if key == Key.f6:
            pyautogui.click(button='left')

    def on_release(key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            # Stop listener
            return False

    with Listener(
            on_press=on_press,
            on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()


window = tk.Tk()

title = tk.Label(
    master = window,
    text = 'Autoclicker'
)

button = tk.Button(
    master=window,
    text='click me',
    command=helper,
    height=10,
    width=20
)

button.pack()
title.pack()



window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start the method as a new thread:

```
import _thread


def helper():
    # helper function for thread call
    _thread.start_new_thread(clicker)
```

This will leave the main thread to `mainloop`and should prevent the window from freezing.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didnt do exactly as you suggested but i did use threading, I'll add my final code above! :)